# How to retrieve documents from list?

Tags: 2013, wss-3.0, lookup-column

I created a simple Custom List in **WSS3**. I also created a Document Library with an additional column field which is a lookup to the Custom List that I created before. Now when I am on the Custom List view I would like to retrieve, for each item of the list, all the linked documents. How can I achieve that?

FYI with **SharePoint 2013** I achieved that with a Quick Step in the Custom List that creates a link button to the Document Library view with a certain query (using FilterField and FilterValue). Please keep in mind that I don't know if that solution is correct and I would like another simpler solution also because I can't find a way to create Quick Steps in WSS3.

EDIT: Just so you know I am looking for a solution INTEGRATED within SharePoint, I'd rather not code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple server object model to achieve this

you need to iterate each SPListitem and inside that call a function which will take item id as parameter and then query doc library to get desired items based on that

```
foreach(SPListitem item in list.items)
 {
   lst.add( GetAllDocs(item.ID));
 }

 public list<Documents> GetAllDocs(int id)
 {
      //Query Doc lib here based on id USE CAML

 }
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Where do I have to put that code? I am very confident with C# but only with desktop/web applications, never coded with SharePoint. Also CAML is a way to query right?